# Get the soap request skeleton

Tags: soap, wsdl, soapui

I am using the soapUI core (classes) to invoke operation for the given WSDL.

I am trying to get the soap request skeleton of a given operation.

Is there any method in WsdlOperation, WsdlRequest that return the skeleton of the soap request. for example:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"
soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding">

<soap:Header>
</soap:Header>

<soap:Body>

    <soap:Fault>

    </soap:Fault>
</soap:Body>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please check this and see if it is useful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43092010/changing-the-request-xml-in-load-script/43115772#43115772?

Comment: tanks, the method buildEmptyMessage() from SoapMessageBuilder is used to get the soap request skeleton.